# If my staging index is empty, why is `git rm` deleting a file that isn't there?

Tags: git, git-rm, git-index

According to the `git rm` documentation, this is how it behaves:

> Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index

If I just did a commit and my index is empty, executing `git rm some_file` will stage the deletion of `some_file`. I would expect `rm` to not do anything. Why is it deleting a nonexistent file and what is the final effect on the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that the index *isn't* empty after a commit.

In fact, it contains exactly what it had before-and-during the commit.

I'm not sure where this notion comes from.  It's true that `git commit` has a flag spelled `--allow-empty`, which perhaps makes it look like the index would be empty at this point, but it's the spelling of the flag that's misleading: what it allows is an empty *diff*, rather than an empty *commit*.

It's also true that `git add` adds new stuff to the index, but in the case of a file that's already there, the new stuff being added is just displacing the old entry that's already there.  (Perhaps the spelling of `git add` is what leads people to assume that the index is empty after a commit?)

(One other slightly peculiar bit is that `git rm` also adds something: specifically, a record to say that "this path-name, which does exist in the `HEAD` commit, should not exist in the next commit."  This is because the index plays a dual role: it's not *just* "what to put in the next commit", but also a cache to speed up git scanning through your work-tree.  You can in fact remove the index file entirely, which de-stages everything but doesn't schedule anything for removal: git just re-builds the index from the `HEAD` commit in this case.)

Comment: You say "I'm not sure where this notion comes from". I think it is from statements like this: "the Index is your proposed next commit" (from [here](https://git-scm.com/blog)). Immediately after a commit I have nothing proposed for my next commit and so I would expect the index to be empty. However that post goes on to explain that "Git populates [the index] with a list of all the file contents that were last checked out into your working directory and what they looked like when they were originally checked out"